# How to change the format of text file

Tags: fortran

I am trying to format my text file containing data in the given below format to the format `(i4, 2i3, i5, i7, 2f8.3, i5, f6.1, 1x, a20)`.

I tried to write the program like this

```
 Program formating
    implicit none

    open (1,FILE='C:/FORTRAN/new.txt',status='old',action='read')
    read (1,111) 

    open (2,FILE='C:/FORTRAN/703.txt',status='new',action='write')
    !format(4x,i4,2i8,2i8,2f8.3,i8,f8.1,a9)
    write(2,112)
111 format(5x,i4,6x,2i2,4x,i4,2x,2f2.3,5x,i3,3x,f3.1,1x,a7)

112 format(i4,2i3,i5,i7,2f8.3,i5,f6.1,1x,a20)

    end program
```

but it is not working. Can anybody help me with this?

```
2015      01      01    0531  999999  28.017  82.250     701     0.0 AMBAPUR
2015      01      02    0531  999999  28.017  82.250     701    14.8 AMBAPUR
2015      01      03    0531  999999  28.017  82.250     701    12.5 AMBAPUR
2015      01      04    0531  999999  28.017  82.250     701     0.0 AMBAPUR
```

Comment: In what way is it "not working"?  I do notice, though, that you aren't actually transferring any data in from/out to files.

Comment: i donot have column heads in data so i need to assign column heads in the text file or i need to define integer and real variable in the fortran